# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in swift, but I have check option value

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports

I collected some user crash logs from the Xcode > Window  > Organizer > crashes.
it is very strange.

It shows a "*Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*" error on line 3 below, but this line code already uses an **if**  to check.

And I don't think  line number is wrong after log be parsed, any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

```swift
        model.weekday = workout.startDate.dayOfWeek()
        model.shortDate = workout.startDate.toString(format: "MM/dd")
        if let totalEnergyBurned = workout.totalEnergyBurned { // Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping 
            model.kilocalorie = (Int)(round(totalEnergyBurned.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.kilocalorie())))
        }
```

The crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100cdaaa4
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [21903]
Triggered by Thread:  17


Thread 17 name:
Thread 17 Crashed:
0   DunDun                          0x0000000100cdaaa4 Swift runtime failure: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value + 0 (DDWorkout.swift:0)
1   DunDun                          0x0000000100cdaaa4 specialized static DDWorkout.convert(_:) + 1936 (DDWorkout.swift:59)
2   DunDun                          0x0000000100cda868 specialized static DDWorkout.convert(_:) + 1364 (DDWorkout.swift:59)
3   DunDun                          0x0000000100cb0a90 static DDWorkout.convert(_:) + 8 (<compiler-generated>:0)
4   DunDun                          0x0000000100cb0a90 completion #1 (_:error:) in HealthKitStorage.getTotalWorkout(callback:) + 752
5   DunDun                          0x0000000100cb0ecc closure #1 in HealthKitStorage.getTotalWorkout(callback:) + 496 (HealthKitStorage.swift:55)
6   DunDun                          0x0000000100cb1590 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed HKSampleQuery, @guaranteed [HKSample]?, @guaranteed Error?) -> () + 132 (<compiler-generated>:0)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000193359a84 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1466)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019335b81c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000193363004 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 620 (inline_internal.h:2557)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000193363c34 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 456 (queue.c:3862)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019336e4bc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 764 (queue.c:6589)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001df2d27a4 _pthread_wqthread + 276 (pthread.c:2437)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001df2d974c start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)



Thread 17 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x00000001e2b66eb7   x2: 0x0000000000000002   x3: 0x00000001a2d8e1b0
    x4: 0x00000000000062dc   x5: 0x00000001012329c0   x6: 0x0000000000000142   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x000000016facf0e0   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000297a6fa57  x11: 0x000f000280cf4a00
   x12: 0x000000000000000a  x13: 0x0000000280cf4a90  x14: 0x000000009f285800  x15: 0x00000001f5dfdee0
   x16: 0x00000001a823473c  x17: 0xe52c29819e292a34  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000197650b94
   x20: 0x00000035312f3131  x21: 0x00000002802ee2e0  x22: 0x0000000197650b40  x23: 0x00000001f64c5848
   x24: 0x0000000101210d70  x25: 0x000000016face650  x26: 0x00000002805ed140  x27: 0xa119cee65a67aed3
   x28: 0xe500000000000000   fp: 0x000000016face740   lr: 0x0000000100cda868
    sp: 0x000000016face650   pc: 0x0000000100cdaaa4 cpsr: 0x80000000
   esr: 0xf2000001  Address size fault
```

Comment: the crash function is `DDWorkout.convert`, please check the content of that function

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that 3 lines of code is *DDWorkout.convert " content ,  line 59 is  "if let totalEnergyBurned = workout.totalEnergyBurned "

Comment: So it's crashing on the optional binding itself.   Is `workout` perhaps defined as an implicitly unwrapped optional?   I would have expected the first line to crash in that case.   Is its `totalEnergyBurned` property a stored or computed property?  If you put a break point on that line, what does the debugger show you as the value for `workout.totalEnergyBurned`?

Comment: @ChipJarred   
I think it stored property.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkout/1615491-totalenergyburned
When I debug it, it cannot reproduce, only got some crash logs from users device or my device sometimes.

Comment: I think even if u do nil check for ```totalEnergyBurned```, ```totalEnergyBurned.doubleValue``` can still be nil.  Thats what causing the crash.

Comment: @udi at least according to Apple's docs,`totalEnergyBurned` returns an `Optional<HKQuantity>`, which is what OP is testing for `nil` on.  However, also according to Apple docs , `HKQuantity.doubleValue(for:)` method returns `Double` *not* `Optional<Double>`, so that ought not be causing the crash.

Comment: The first thing I noticed from the link to the documentation is that `totalEnergyBurned` is deprecated.  A quick Google search didn't find alternatives.  If you change your target OS version (just temporarily) so Xcode gives you the deprecation warning, does it say what to use instead?

Comment: Actually the alternative was glaring at me in the docs, and I just didn't register it.  It looks like `statistics(for:)` or `allStatistics` is the thing to use.

Comment: Thanks, I will test the new method according to Apple's doc. something like this:
workout.statistics(for: calorieType)?.sumQuantity()

Comment: maybe your `workout` object is already released

Comment: so when you access `non-exist-object`'s properties, your app will crash. If-let is for safety unwrap optional type, not for checking the existence of the object.

Comment: @QuangHà then why didn’t it crash on any of the lines just before the `if let`?

Comment: is there any another thread access your object?

Comment: @QuangHà nope. This crash is so weired.

Comment: the problem could lie on Apple's side - just having a property being non-optional in Swift can still mean that in the Objective-C implementation of the class done by Apple the value can be set to `nil`. I had a similar case where I could set a variable to nil in Objective C and then provoke that crash when trying to use the object in Swift (that was with an AVPlayer)

Comment: @TheEye I will keep eye on whether there is such a crash later